# Is there a good way to Learn Joomla Plugin Devlopment

Tags: joomla

Learn Joomla Plugin devlopment.Can somebody give me any refrence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://learnwebdesignonline.com/tutorial-joomla-plugin
Read this.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know PHP then you are off to a great start.  I would find some other well written plugins that are GPL and start customizing them.  This will get you exposed to Joomla's layered MVC architecture.

If you don't know PHP, grab a book on Amazon with good reviews and start writting PHP before you jump into a complex framework like Joomla.
Mikr

Answer (score 0):

[docs.joomla.org/Plugin_Development](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin_Development)..Ck this out